# How could young Spock be holding a photo of older Spock?

Tags: star-trek, spock, star-trek-beyond

In Star Trek Beyond, how could young Spock be holding a photo of an older and deceased Ambassador Spock; are they not the same person?

Comment: Did you not watch the 2009 Star Trek movie that this is the second sequel to?

Comment: Frankly, I'm glad you asked this question. You should not have to know everything about the Star Trek universe in order to ask a question. I think the real answer is, they are not the same person. Spock Prime, that's the older Spock, is from a different timeline. He's not made of the same essence as this Kelvin Spock. He just looks/acts/is like him.

Comment: Thank you @JerryNixon-TOS for recognizing that it would be absurd to expect the star trek franchise to make much progress by taking on an elitist attitude and expect anyone watching future episodes/movies to know everything that was suggested in every previous iteration of any version in order to enjoy it. I watched Star Trek before it was cool, but didn't keep up with everything, so I forgot a few things. Asking if I watched a previous episode does NOT answer the question and is NOT deserving of an upvote. Yes, I watched it, but it was 8 years ago, a lot has happened in my life since then...

Answer (score 15):

*Star Trek* (2009), *Star Trek into Darkness* (2013), and *Star Trek Beyond* (2016) occur in an alternate timeline / reality - so there are two different Spocks. "Old Spock" is from the 'original' timeline and has journeyed via artificial black hole to an alternate universe.

> The alternate reality was a new reality created when a temporal
>   incursion caused by time travel of the Narada, a Romulan mining vessel
>   from the year 2387, disrupted the time continuum. Accidentally
>   traveling back to the year 2233, Nero, the Narada's captain, attacked
>   the USS Kelvin. The attack resulted in the deaths of several crew
>   members of the Kelvin, including George Kirk and Richard Robau, and
>   the destruction of the Kelvin itself. Spock arrived to the alternate
>   reality in 2258 and was captured by Nero, who used red matter to
>   destroy Vulcan. However, Nero's attacks united the crew of the USS
>   Enterprise, who foiled his attempt to destroy Earth. (Star Trek)

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alternate_reality

If you are familiar with the [Mirror Universe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_universe) from TOS and DS9 - it's the same kind of concept (although, a different alternate universe)

Comment: AFAIK it's not been conclusively shown or said that the Mirror Universive is an alternate universe or different timeline, like many other examples in the franchise. It appears to be a special case, because no matter how far major events seem to diverge from the prime universe, many characters are somehow preserved, yet their personalities are often diametrically opposed. This doesn't appear to be consistent with or analogous to a "single point of divergence" alternate timeline like the Kelvin timeline/Abramsverse at all.

Comment: So how does young Spock get a picture of someone (old Spock or anyone else) who is in a different timeline? Was the picture sent back/forward in time, or laterally, across timelines?

Comment: @KevinFegan - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ppo5YIYwTM - we don't see the photo being given, but this does demonstrate that the two have come into physical contact. If it didn't happen then, it may have happened some later time, or been sent to young Spock

Comment: Thanks. I had just watched this movie `Star Trek (2009)` about an hour ago, and that clip does explain the possibilities for the source of the picture.

Comment: Young!Spock received the photo when he was informed Old!Spock had died in *Star Trek Beyond* and was given Old!Spock's effects. Among them was the picture.